# delete cookies using capybara webkit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, capybara-webkit

I recently started using capybara-webkit in order to speed up my acceptance tests. 90% of my tests run using the standard capybara DSL but some are slightly different.

One of the main ones that I am having trouble with is deleting cookies. Previously I used the following:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

but this does not work with capybara-webkit. Receive this error:

```
 undefined method `delete_cookie' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x007f86cb068b88> (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone know how I can delete the cookies using capybara-webkit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`clear_cookies` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara-webkit/Capybara/Webkit/Browser#clear_cookies-instance_method):

```
page.driver.browser.clear_cookies
```